# Udev- How do I find out which subsystem a device belongs to?

Tags: udev

For example, I have device /dev/sdb. How do I find out it's udev subsystem?

Answer (score 23):

```
$ udevadm info -q all -a /dev/sdb
```

**NOTE:** the above queries the UDEV database for device information, `info`, we're querying for all information, `-q all`, and we're walking all the attributes under `/sys` pertaining to this device label.

*excerpt*

```
   --attribute-walk|-a
       Print all sysfs properties of the specified device that can be used 
       in udev rules to match the specified device. It prints all devices
       along the chain, up to the root of sysfs that can be used in udev 
       rules.
```

#### Example

Here's my `/dev/sda` device.

```
$ udevadm info -q all -a /dev/sda | grep parent
walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
and the attributes from one single parent device.
  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0':
  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0':
  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0':
  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1':
  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2':
  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
```

#### Differences between these 2 commands

@sepero's answer is showing information just pertaining to the UDEV device at the leaf node.

#### Sepero's answer

```
$ udevadm info -q all -n /dev/sda > udevadm_info_1.txt
```

- [single udevadm output](http://pastebin.com/NHg9pydA)

#### slm's answer

My answer shows the attributes as it walks the entire `/sys` chain hierarchy of devices.

```
$ udevadm info -q all -a /dev/sda > udevadm_info_2.txt
```

- [nested udevadm output](http://pastebin.com/w8mAWm0C)

You can see the difference between these two.

```
$ diff -y udevadm_info_1.txt udevadm_info_2.txt  \
    > udevadm_info_diff.txt
```

- [side by side diff of the above 2 files](http://pastebin.com/a1gXxqad)

**NOTE:** I'm running on Fedora 19, using version 204 of `udevadm`:

```
$ udevadm --version
204
```

Comment: Why this complex command rather than `udevadm info -a -n /dev/sdb`?

Comment: @Gilles - This one dumps all the ATTRS for all the parent nodes.

Comment: So does mine — the output is identical.

Comment: Gilles - You on Debian? What version of udevadm? When I run the above 2 commands I get these 2 files. [single udevadm output](http://pastebin.com/NHg9pydA) vs. [nested udevadm output](http://pastebin.com/w8mAWm0C). In looking at the output I think the single command is just combining all the output of all the parents while my version shows which parents the ATTRS are deriving from.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/NHg9pydA is the output from `udevadm info -q all`, not from `udevadm info -a`. I think `-a` is a shortcut for `-q all --attribute-walk`. Or is this different on your version? I don't remember this changing, but then I haven't used Fedora in years (but why would a distribution patch this?).

Comment: @Gilles - sorry those descriptions are backwards. The descriptions in the updates to my A are correct.

Comment: @Gilles - this command `udevadm info -q all -a /dev/sda` is equivalent to what I showed with the nested commands. I'll modify my A to reflect this abbreviated version vs. my monstrosity.

Answer (score 12):

[`udevadm info`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/udevadm.8.html#OPTIONS) provides this kind of information.

If you specifically want the subsystem:

```
udevadm info -n /dev/sdb -q property | sed -n 's/SUBSYSTEM=//p'
```

When you're writing udev rules, the most useful command is

```
udevadm info -a -n /dev/sdb
```

This prints out rules that you can use to match the device in udev rules. The first block is about the device itself, and the subsequent blocks are about its ancestors in the device tree. The only caveat is that you cannot mix keys that correspond to different ancestors. For example, given this excerpt

```
KERNEL=="sdb"
SUBSYSTEM=="block"
…
KERNELS=="5:0:0:0"
SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
DRIVERS=="sd"
ATTRS{model}=="Yoyodyne Diskinator"
…
KERNELS=="0000:00:1f.2"
SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
DRIVERS=="ahci"
```

then you can match this device with `SUBSYSTEM=="block", SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi", ATTRS{model}="Yoyodyne Diskinator"` or with `SUBSYSTEM=="block", SUBSYSTEMS=="pci", DRIVERS="ahci"` but not with `SUBSYSTEM=="block", SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi", ATTRS{model}="Yoyodyne Diskinator", DRIVERS="ahci"`.

Another way to obtain information for use in rules is with

```
udevadm info -q property -n /dev/sdb --export
```

This prints device property values of the form `KEY=VALUE` which you can use as `ENV{KEY}=="VALUE"` in udev rules.

If your device doesn't have a `/dev` entry, you can refer to it with a path under `/sys` instead, e.g.

```
udevadm info -a -p /sys/block/sdb
```

(not a useful example in this case — this is useful for devices whose category isn't common and don't have an entry under `/dev` yet).

When you change udev rules, they are read automatically; however, they are only applied to devices that are subsequently plugged into the system. To apply the new rules to an already-connected device, use `udevadm trigger` (with options to restrict the application to certain devices).

Answer (score 5):

```
$ udevadm info -q all -n /dev/sdb
```

Comment: The difference b/w this approach and mine is that this shows just the leaf node in `/sys` for `/dev/sdb`. The other approach shows the entire tree hierarchy of the leaf node along with the branches.